# error with restful service ( jersey )

Tags: rest, service, jersey

My RESTful service already works yesterday but suddenly an error appear. I searched all the answers and nothing solved the error. Sometimes the error is deploying the project and sometimes when I try to acces the RESTful service.

The pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>rpc_server</groupId>
<artifactId>rpc_server</artifactId>
<version>3.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.35</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

And Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"     
                    version="3.0">



<display-name>rpc_server</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.rpc_server</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And the error is:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: La ejecución del Servlet lanzó una
>   excepción
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   causa raíz
>
> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class
>   javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status does not implement the requested
>   interface javax.ws.rs.core.Response$StatusType
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.getStatus(ContainerResponse.java:599)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse$CommittingOutputStream.commitWrite(ContainerResponse.java:157)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse$CommittingOutputStream.write(ContainerResponse.java:134)
>     sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(Unknown Source)
>     sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(Unknown Source)
>     sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(Unknown Source)
>     sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(Unknown Source)
>     java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
>     java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
>     com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.writeToAsString(ReaderWriter.java:191)
>     com.sun.jersey.core.provider.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeToAsString(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:128)
>     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:88)
>     com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:58)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:302)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1510)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: I dont know why but I must add the following dependency too:

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-m01</version>
</dependency>


solved,thanks.